# Spring JDBC template without Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Is there Java library like Spring JDBC Template, **with same quality of code and documentation and similar data access exceptions hierarchy**, but without dependancies on other Spring modules (core/beans/context modules according to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring-jdbc has direct dependency to the following libraries: `spring-core`, `spring-beans` and `spring-tx`. The rest of the dependencies are optional, so you don't need them actually.

If these dependencies are already a lot for you, then you might have a look at [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check Apache DbUtils lib. Spring-core, -beans and -tx is really more than I need. However, it seems that DbUtils doesn't handle exceptions in suce nice way as Spring JDBC Template :-(

Comment: I've worked with pure JDBC, implemented our own library, used EJB, tried Hibernate.. All these approaches have their upsides and downsides, for sure. But among all of these, I think that Spring JDBC offers the simplest compact solution for database operations.

Answer (score 9):

A minor correction to the accepted answer. As far as I can tell there is at least one more jar required. It comes into play exactly when data access exception hierarchy is accessed (an exception is thrown by underlying database driver and it's wrapped into Spring exception). The jar is spring-asm (byte-code manipulation). 
I discovered it accidentally when I had a problem in my SQL query and stack trace showed something like MissingClassException.
(I would to prefer just to add a comment to the answer, but it looks I'm not eligible yet).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Just today have I removed some unused spring modules, and only kept jdbc-related ones. I will probably need to readd -asm :-(

Answer (score 6):

There is another alternative way very close to `JdbcTemplate`, you can use the library [`sql2o`](http://www.sql2o.org/) which has just `slf4j` and `guava` dependencies. See below a simple example from their web site. Also, as a bonus you still get better performance as you can see on [this benchmark](https://github.com/aaberg/sql2o) (disclosure: I'm NOT a member of **`sql2o`** project, I'm just using it in a project).

```java
public class Task{
    private int id;
    private String category;
    private Date dueDate;
    // getters and setters here
}
```

```java
Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

String sql =
    "SELECT id, category, duedate " +
    "FROM tasks " +
    "WHERE category = :category";

try(Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
    List<Task> tasks = con.createQuery(sql)
        .addParameter("category", "foo")
        .executeAndFetch(Task.class);
}
```

Comment: You probably intended to say "I'm *NOT* a member of sql2o project"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was a typo and now is fixed. Thanks for your attention!