# How to get rid of many placeholders (question marks) in java sql statements

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to insert a row to table using JDBC. But table has a big number of columns, so I don't want to specify all of them into a statement. Is there another way of specifying column values?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(?, ?, ?, ..., ?)
```

I hope there is another way to do it without a big number of placeholders.

**EDITED:**

I mean, can I just edit query like `...` meaning that it expects a many values and dynamically set values with incremented index or something else. And yes as @f1sh mentioned the problem is in the number of placeholders, but not in case of *laziness*, more in case of convenience and cleanliness.

P.S.: for some <s>funny enterprise requirements</s> reasons I can not use JPA frameworks :)

Comment: And this is why JPA frameworks exist. If you're not able to use one then you're going to be stuck doing it the long-winded way and using the various `setFoo` methods on your `PreparedStatement` to set all of the values in the correct order in your insert string.

Comment: These question marks are placeholder in a prepared statement. This is the shortest way to do it correctly and safely. What else do you want?

Comment: `?` are safe against SQL injection. If you want to automate this, then use an ORM. Any ORM will do.

Comment: See my edit about SqlBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Another option is to write your own or use [SqlBuilder](https://openhms.sourceforge.io/sqlbuilder/)

> SqlBuilder changes that whole scenario by wrapping the SQL syntax within very lightweight and easy to use Java objects which follow the "builder" paradigm (similar to StringBuilder). This changes many common SQL syntactical, runtime errors into Java compile-time errors! Let's dive right in to some quick examples to to see how it all works.

You can use Spring's [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) and use variable names

```
String SQL = INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES((:id),...);

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("id", "idValue");
//...
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL, parameters) > 0;
```

> Template class with a basic set of JDBC operations, allowing the use of named parameters rather than traditional '?' placeholders.

If you can (safely) use [dynamic query](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/parameterized-sql-query-dynamic-sql-query/#gref)  using `Statement`:

> ```
> Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement(“SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='” + user + “‘ AND password='” + pass + “‘ limit 0,1”);
>
> ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
> ```

You can use it only on closed values so there will be no option for SQL injection

Comment: Having never used this before, can it be used as a standalone dependency in a project? Or do you need to have other bits of Spring in play as well?

Comment: Isn't this even more work? OP's question is basically "I am too lazy to even use `?` as a placeholder"

Comment: @JonK This are the required jars for spring-jdbc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415139/spring-jdbc-template-without-spring

Comment: @f1sh I'm not sure this is the question, because you must give all values